# Do I need an HR letter for an Interview Schengen Visa in Austria

Tags: schengen-visas, austria

I’m an Egyptian citizen living in Egypt, and I have an interview for a job in Austria. 
For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question I might not be able to get an HR letter from my current employer by the time of my application submission appointment.
I do have the financial means to support myself during the duration of my visit, and I have a previous traveling record in and out of the Schengen area.
My question is, do I still need to submit an HR letter to the Austrian Consulate in Cairo? or would I have zero chances of being granted a visa without any proof of employment?

Comment: Haven't you got payslips?

Comment: @michael those are sent by email, they are neither signed nor stamped, plus pay slips in general doesn’t meet the requirements of an HR letter for the consulate as they don’t contain an approval from the company during the travel period